# how to showing result value in react website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am new in react, how to showing (accountInfo[4]) value in my website?

when i changed to

`const setPaid = (accountInfo[4])`

> TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useAccountInfo from '../abi/useAccountInfo';
import Value from '../utils/value';

const Hero = () => {
  const accountInfo = useAccountInfo();

  const setPaid = console.log(accountInfo);

return (
  <div>
      <Value value={setPaid}/>
  </div>
);

export default Hero;
```

this the result in console

[image]

this my useAccountInfo.js file

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useWallet } from 'use-wallet'
import { BigNumber } from 'ethers';
import useBlock from './useBlock'
import useTokenInfo from './useTokenInfo';

const useAccountInfo = () => {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState(BigNumber.from(0));
  const {account, ethereum} = useWallet();
  const block = useBlock();
  const tokenInfo = useTokenInfo();

  const fetchAccountInfo = async () => {
    if (!account) {
      setAccountInfo(BigNumber.from(0));
      return;
    }

    const accountInfo = await tokenInfo?.accountInfo();
    setAccountInfo(accountInfo);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAccountInfo();
  }, [block, account, ethereum, tokenInfo]);

  return accountInfo;
}

export default useAccountInfo;
```

Comment: What is the return value of `useAccountInfo`? Is that a array?

Comment: seems like `accountInfo` is `undefined` for a few render cycles, so a quick fix is to add a check. like `if (!accountInfo) return null` in the render function, then try to access `accountInfo[4]`. Altho looks like it starts off as a BigNumber first and not an array so you might have to check for that as well.

Comment: sorry i am new in react, i was copied some source code from another project

Comment: You're setting set paid to the result of a console.log? That doesn't seem right at all..    .const setPaid = console.log(accountInfo);

Comment: i want get value [4] from the result, i don't know how to set it